# Receiving Unable to expand error(Error-1 - Undefined error:0) when attempting to open zip. Only on Mac-os Catalina

Tags: php, zip, macos-catalina

I am not able to open zips greater than 4GB that have been generated with Ne-Lexa/php-zip library. Compression method: deflated.

When attempting to unzip from finder using unarchiver, I receive

```
Unable to expand zip into folder.(Error -1 - Undefinined error: 0)
```

Receiving the below error when attempting to unzip from the command line:

```
Archive: BakersBigCatalinaWineMixerZip.zip inflating: 
09_ProPresenterFiles/04_Preteen/1910 Preteen.pro6plx inflating: 
09_ProPresenterFiles/02_K3/1910 K3.pro6plx inflating: 
09_ProPresenterFiles/03_K5Plus/1910 K5Plus.pro6plx file #4: bad zipfile 
offset (local header sig): 2632229990
```

When looking at the detailed information on the zip, I see that the text below displays for the failing file.

```
There are an extra -4294967280 bytes preceding this file.
```

Again this only happens on Mac's latest OS. No issues otherwise.

How can I programmatically modify local headers on zip in order to correct this error?

Comment: With what library? I do not see a coding question here.

Comment: This is a zip generated by Ne-Lexa/php-zip library. Compression method: deflated.